# Image-upload and manipulation, then store as blob in DB fails

Tags: php, mysql, image, mysqli

I don't get it.
Goal as described in Title, I did a multipart-form and **simple upload a Image to DB works (!)**, but...

my next step is to mod the uploaded file. I want to add a Logo. Then my problem begins.

I added a lot of debug information and recognized step by step: The binary Image-Data of a simple uploaded File (which is well saved in the DB!) is different to the binary resulted from imagecopy (which is not saved in the DB).

So I need some help. Please take a quick look:

```
<?php  
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');
ini_set('error_log', 'php-errors.log');

if (! isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}else{
    $client_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
$connect = mysqli_connect("mysql..de", "", "", "");  
if(isset($_POST["insert"]))  
{  
    if( isset($_POST["copyrights"]) ){
        $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));  
        /*
        // start adding Logo
        $stampfile=getcwd().'/Logo2.jpg';
        $stamp=imagecreatefromjpeg($stampfile);
        
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

        
        $marge_right = 10;
        $marge_bottom = 10;
        $sx = imagesx($stamp);
        $sy = imagesy($stamp);

        imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
        
        $file="";
        
        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($im,NULL,100);
        $file = ob_get_contents();
        ob_get_clean();
        imagedestroy($im);
        //end adding logo
        */
        echo "file-enght(string/blob):".strlen($file);
        echo $file;
        $query = "INSERT INTO myjoints_images(image,uploadDate,state,ip) VALUES ('$file',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),NULL,'$client_ip')";  
        if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
        {  
            //ok
        }  
    }else{
        echo '<script>alert("Upload fehlgeschlagen! Du musst die Nutzungsvereinbarung akzeptieren!")</script>';  
    }
}  

?>
```

Results are:
If I just upload a Picture, **Image is stored in DB**, type/size is:

```
file-enght(string/blob):793506����\0JFIF\0\0`\0`\0\0��-Exif\0\0MM\0*\0\0\0\02\0\0\0\0\0\0\0bGF\0\0\0\0\0\0\0GI\0\0\0\0\0X\0\0��\0\0\0\0\0\0\0v��...
```

If I run my mod, **Image is NOT stored in DB**, type/size is:

```
file-enght(string/blob):551227����JFIF``��a]�|����F�2��,6�As����@�ط���U�Lq�T�Dy8Vf<4(A�P˴0� �'�;#)�~h�T!e����gE1+!C;yk�r���>zū+�k�ҍ��+�������m8��iGh��m-9yU���j��{7�z���...
```

I uploaded every time the same picture.

Comment: Use a prepared statement, `addslashes()` is not to be used for database inserts. And why would you expect two completely different files to be identical?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot escape data for database storage using `addslashes()`. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Something like this should work, though there are issues with storing large amounts of data using the old mysqli extension. PDO is a better and more modern way to go.

```
if (! isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}else{
    $client_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
$connect = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "database");  
if(isset($_POST["insert"]))  
{  
    if( isset($_POST["copyrights"]) ){
        // start adding Logo
        $stampfile = './Logo2.jpg';
        $stamp = imagecreatefromjpeg($stampfile);
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
        $mr = 10;
        $mb = 10;
        $sx = imagesx($stamp);
        $sy = imagesy($stamp);
        imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $mr, imagesy($im) - $sy - $mb, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

        // output and destroy the image before getting buffer to ensure we get everything
        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($im, null, 100);
        imagedestroy($im);
        $file = ob_get_clean();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO myjoints_images(image,uploadDate,state,ip) VALUES (?,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),NULL,?)";
        // of course you should check these statements for successful execution
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("bs", $file, $client_ip);
        $stmt->execute();
    }else{
        echo '<script>alert("Upload fehlgeschlagen! Du musst die Nutzungsvereinbarung akzeptieren!")</script>';  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your output, remove addslashes and base64_encode did the trick